# how to create catalina.out log in tomcat 6 or 7

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, log4j, tomcat7, tomcat6

Can any one please help me to set catalina.out log in tomcat 6.?

This is my logging.property file

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = admin.

5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/admin].level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/admin].handlers = 4admin.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 5host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

# For example, set the com.xyz.foo logger to only log SEVERE
# messages:
#org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.level=FINE
```

I need to enable this for debugging the maxThreads related issue..

Thanks

Comment: In case anyone else using Windows and tomcat stumbles here through google, the `.bat` will not produce `catalina.out`, only the `.sh` files, so fire up cygwin, git bash, or babun!

Answer (score 3):

You really don't want to enable logging of absolutely everything. That will slow down your Tomcat instance significantly.

The logging config looks fine.

catalina.out is just the redirected stdout (i.e. the output of the console logger) and that redirection is configured in $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh

Everything that Tomcat logs to stdout will also be logged to $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.yyyy-mm-dd.log so you can also look there. Note anything an application writes to stdout will only appear in catalina.out

Comment: Thanks mark. 
can u please help me to find this "CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh" path..? i am working in tomcat 6 (window OS) i cant able to find the path specified by u
Thanks,

Comment: Mark do u any idea about how to make tomcat to print thread related logs? we need this log to debug the thread related issue...
 For example 
Name: http-bio-8080-exec-2
State: TIMED_WAITING
Total blocked: 1,652  Total waited: 66,128

Stack trace: 
java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)

Comment: $CATALINA_HOME is your Tomcat installation directory. If you are on Windows did you use the Windows installer and install Tomcat as a service? If so, there will be no catalina.out. stdout is routed to a different file when running as a service (I forget which) but it is in the logs directory.

Comment: For a thread dump, the service control panel includes an option to generate a thread dump.

Comment: I installed tomcat as a service. In log directory i can see the following logs catalina,localhost,stdout,manager,host-manager,stderr,jakarta_service and admin logs but i cant able to see any of the thread details in those logs... it would be helpful if i got those details in tomcat logs... is there any way to redirect or write thread dumb to any of those tomcat logs?

Comment: Thanks mark..i can get the thread details from thread dumb as u said.. but i need this to be configure/redirected to tomcat logs.. Since we are debugging this in production environment.. it would be helpful if we have any configuration for this...

Comment: FYI, We are using tomcat 6 and 7 for our web project which is developed in java..Now suddenly tomcat is not able to handle any request.. we tried to host the tomcat manager but this too in loading state.. We are not intimated by any errors or warnings in any of the tomcat logs.. we suspected Anti-virus may block the tomcat host or port and tomcat thread may increased to default level(200)..now finally we suspect more on tomcat thread so we need this logs to do more research on that..

Comment: @MarkThomas, My catalina.yyyy-mm-dd.log only logs in startup of service, and after that nothing log in it. Do you know what's wrong with it?

Answer (score -2):

To enable logging :

1) put your file in `WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties`,

2) On your java code, instanciate and use your logger :

```
public class MyCLass {
    java.util.logging.Logger logger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
    void method() { logger.info("info log"); }
}
```

[Documentation here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Logging/article.html)

Comment: You have described application logging. The question is about Tomcat's logging.